# Is there a way to migrate SQL Server to Vistadb (Umbraco)

Tags: sql-server, umbraco, vistadb

I am on a shared host and whilst in development (umbraco) I think it would be easier to use VistaDB then package up to install to SQL Server. However, I have already started using SQL Server. Is there a way to migrate my SQL Server (2008) database to VistaDB. I assume the schema is identical but I need a way/tool to move the data to VistaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could migrate to VistaDB in the same way that you want to migrate data from development to production. Create a package from your current SQL Server-based development site, then create a new empty install of Umbraco with a VistaDB database and import the package there.

This would also be a useful dry run to check that migration to production is going to work as smoothly as you expect.

Comment: Yes, this would be the right answer if I could gain access to the admin interface - currently all the nodes are blank and do I cant get to the packager. I have marked this the correct answer though

Comment: If the admin interface is currently borked, isn't copying the database wholesale to VistaDB still going to leave you with a borked admin interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Data Migration Tool in VistaDB to migrate any SQL Server database to VistaDB 4.  If you need an older migration (I think the current Umbraco is still using VDB3 files) contact support through the VistaDB.Net site and someone will help you.

Comment: Other way around.. VistaDB > SQL Server.

Comment: I have actually written several blogs about that:  http://www.vistadb.net/blog/post/2008/03/28/Using-SqlBulkCopy-to-move-data-from-VistaDB-to-SQL-Server.aspx  It is a pain to use the data tools in SQL Server, but it can be done.

Comment: Here is another one (For VDB4) http://www.vistadb.net/blog/post/2009/11/13/Using-SQL-Server-Integration-Services-to-Migration-VistaDB-4-Data.aspx